# Docker-compose: cannot connect api container to Minio container

Tags: docker, amazon-s3, networking, docker-compose, minio

I'm trying to connect my api server to a minio container, i'm using dockercompose like this:

```
  minio:
    image: "minio/minio"
    # volumes:
    #   - ./docker-data/minio/data:/data
    command: minio server /data
    networks:
      - backend
    environment:
      MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: 7PDZZCOFGYUASDCBWW9L
      MINIO_SECRET_KEY: cSqaXmYpTk91asduFJ7ZKsZ+8e2pSLOXfc6ycogq
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
  api:
    image: "applications-api"
    networks:
      - backend
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: test
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
  # command: npm run dockertest

networks:
  backend:
```

But I keep getting this error, the credentials are the same i cannot understand what i'm doing wrong, I appreciate any kind of help.

````
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.22.0.2:443
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16) {
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'NetworkingError',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '172.22.0.2',
  port: 443,
  region: 'eu-central-1',
  hostname: 'minio',
  retryable: true,
  time: 2020-08-28T13:24:39.702Z```
````

Comment: You are trying to connect to port `443`, just should use `9000`.

Comment: (It looks like you've configured the service to talk to the host name `minio`, and it's correctly resolved to a Docker-internal IP address, so you probably have the Docker-level configuration correct.)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is your API tries to connect its own container's localhost.

If so, in your API code:

Try using `host.docker.internal` instead of `localhost` as minio client endpoint.

This will connect your API to the host's localhost.